Hamburger menu isn't sliding
I want make hamburger menu <HamburgerMenu className="Hamburger-Menu" id="HamMenu" style={styles}/> slide on clicking hamburger icon(checkbox) <Hamburger id="ham-icon"/> using #ham-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .Hamburger-Menu  in css but isn't working
Header.jsx:

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import Logo from "./icons/Logo.jsx"
import Hamburger from './icons/Hamburger.jsx'
import HamburgerMenu from './HamburgerMenu.jsx'

function Header(){
    const [headerHeight, setHeaderHeight] = useState()
    const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)

    useEffect(() => {
            const HamMenu = document.getElementById("HamMenu")
            const Header = document.getElementById("top-bar")

            const HamMenuRect = HamMenu.getBoundingClientRect()
            const HeaderRect = Header.getBoundingClientRect()
            
            setHeaderHeight(HeaderRect.height)
            console.log(HeaderRect.height)
            
        }, []
    )
    
    const styles = {
        '--Header-Height' : headerHeight + 'px', 
        '--Window-Width+5' : windowWidth+5 + 'px',
    }

    return(
        <div className="Header" id="top-bar">

            <Logo fill='black' width='70px' height='70px'/>
        
            <div className="button-container">
                <button> Products </button>
                <button> Services </button>
                <button> Company </button>
                <button> Pricing </button>
            </div>
        
            <div>
                <Hamburger id="ham-icon"/>
                <HamburgerMenu className="Hamburger-Menu" id="HamMenu" style={styles}/>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
    
}

export default Header

Hamburger.jsx(checkbox):
import React from "react";
import styles from './Hamburger.module.css'

function Hamburger({...props}){
  return (
      <label className={styles.burger} {...props} htmlFor="burger">
        <input type="checkbox" id="burger"/>
        <span />
        <span />
        <span />
      </label>
  );
};

export default Hamburger;

HamburgerMenu.jsx:

import { useEffect } from "react"

function HamburgerMenu({HamburgerMenu, ...props}){
    
    return(
        <div className={HamburgerMenu} {...props}>
            <ul>
                <li>Portfolio</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Login</li>
                <li>Language: EN</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HamburgerMenu

Index.css:

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Header.jsx */
.Header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    
    background-color: rgb(0, 186, 114);
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 8px 50px;
}

.button-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 50px;

    width: 100%;
}

.button-container button{
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-size: 22px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button-container button:hover{
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
}

.button-container button:active{
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2);
}


.Hamburger-Menu{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 89%);
    top: var(--Header-Height);    /* from Header.jsx */
    left: 100vw;
    
    border: 5px solid hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.Hamburger-Menu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#ham-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .Hamburger-Menu{
    right: 0vw;
}


When you using react you should follow react concept, what is it mean, when you would like to access specific dom element then you should use useRef istead of getElementById in react. Also i believe that you dont need useRef for in your case you can useState variable on your element

Your checkbox is not a sibling of the .Hamburger-Menu element (because it is contained inside the label element), so the adjacent or general sibling selector won't work in this scenario.
Try instead :has():
.Header:has(#burger:checked) .Hamburger-Menu {
   ...
}

or if you want to still use the adjacent sibling selector
label:has(#burger:checked) + .Hamburger-Menu {
   ...
}

